# Kali Linux bootable USB not showing up in boot menu

Tags: disk-utility, usb, partition, unix, big-sur

I am using a 2018 MBA running Big Sur

I wanted to create a persistent bootable USB with Kali Linux and have followed the exact instructions as given in this article: https://medium.com/macoclock/install-kali-linux-live-usb-with-persistence-using-macos-b1574c996491

However after powering on and pressing the option key, the bootable USB does not show up. This is partition containing the OS:

[image]

Here, it shows Bootable "No" but I don't know why. Also this partition is not mounted and Big Sur isn't allowing me to mount it as well and shows an error.

[image]

I am not sure what the issue is here and would be extremely grateful if someone helped out

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me correctly, you can not boot iso9660 images from a partition on Intel Mac computers. At least not directly from the Mac firmware. I am not sure what the author of your linked reference was thinking.

I would recommend following the instructions publish by kali.org. Below are two webpages which together cover the creation of a portable Kali with persistence.

[Making a Kali Bootable USB Drive (macOS/OS X)](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-mac/)

[Adding Persistence to a Kali Linux "Live" USB Drive](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/)

If you are still having problems, then update your question and post a comment below.